# How to diagnose Finder losing icons for folders?

Tags: macos, finder, safari, alfred

After a reboot several strange issues come up from nothing.
Suddenly all system directory lost their icons: Desktop, Home, Downloads, Pictures, Movies... have the normal folder icon. Even in Finder's sidebar.
In console.app I noticed this when Finder opens:

```
09/06/14 16:17:44,722 Finder[250]: Could not find image named '357D167A-6053-47A6-BD22-B028736F98C1'.
09/06/14 16:22:14,810 Finder[250]: Could not find image named 'D54AFEF0-1EF4-43D6-8F3F-84A181AC04B2'.
09/06/14 16:22:14,810 Finder[250]: Could not find image named '357D167A-6053-47A6-BD22-B028736F98C1'.
```

Every time I open Alfred 2 preferences these are reset to default. Themes, workflows, everything is reset.

At last Safari won't connect to service hosted on localhost through https

```
Safari can't open the page because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server. I tried:
```

- rebooting
- repairing permissions
- resetting safari
- reinstalling Alfred
- deleting com.apple.finder.plist
- removing every login item and launch agent

The problem persists and I don't know what causes this or how to fix it. Is there a way to restore the custom folders Finder shows for user default folders?

Here there is the [log](http://pastebin.com/cbTe1QdH) of the boot taken from console.app.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean? Finder?

Comment: What I mean is, if you start in Safe mode or start as different user ? to check if your user is in trouble.

Comment: In safe mode the icons are back.

Comment: So now we know you have a application causing it, and it is not a OS problem. I would guess it is Alfred, so disable/uninstall and try.

Comment: Ok, this is really weird. After the safe boot the Finder issue didn't appear even in normal mode. After another reboot the icons are gone once again. However I completely removed Alfred but the problem persists.

Comment: Nope, that is normal since the Safe boot also does the repairs.

Comment: @Buscar웃 So someone is overwriting something.

Comment: We are going to have to use the Console to see what is going on. Please publish a report (about 50 lines) from the time stamp when you start the computer to see what is it fighting with.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I added a log.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is the entire log since the boot. What else do you need?

Comment: The paste was deleted. I updated the link.

Comment: here you go->  com.apple.IconServicesAgent[248]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x117] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x20b] - extension: ics, UTI: com.apple.ical.ics, fileType: ????.
quicklookd[310]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x403] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x303] - extension: ics, UTI: com.apple.ical.ics, fileType: ???? request size:16 scale: 1

Comment: @Buscar웃 I can't find anything useful about this error. What should I do?

Comment: try this mkdir ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices  This recreates the com.apple.IconServices directory, which apparently gets itself deleted from time to time.

Comment: I deleted and recreated that folder. Apparently it worked. The icons are back even after 2 reboots. Thank you. Can you post an answer?

Comment: ok, will do, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in Terminal

`mkdir ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices`

This recreates the com.apple.IconServices directory, which apparently gets itself deleted from time to time.

Comment: Guess what? Today I turned the mac on and the icons disappeared again.

Comment: Just made a clean install to 10.10 beta and after a reboot... same problem. It's obviously some program I have installed but I can't figure out which is.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, the disappearing icons trick. I had this happen a long while back, and it was pretty simple to fix. I deleted one file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

Then rebooted and the problem was solved. I think what happens is something can cause the Finder preferences to get corrupted, so deleting the .plist will force a new file to be created upon the next reboot.

Comment: The first thing I tried. Nope, it does nothing.

Comment: Interesting. Have you cleaned caches, and repaired permissions?

Comment: @l'Ll Yes, I have.

Comment: Well it's pretty safe to say that something that is installed is causing the issue. You'll want to try and remember when it was exactly that problem started. Do you possibly have the SIMBL plugin installed (which colors the sidebar folders) or anything similar?

Comment: I made a clean install a few days ago. The system is pretty empty. I have no SIMBL plugins or installed any software recently.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have would be to make another user account, login and see if the issue persists. If it doesn't then you could start using that one and remove the other. One other option is to boot into recovery mode and do a reinstall. Generally with icons disappearing it's fairly easy to track down something that is causing it, although without a more detailed console log it's really only speculation for the most part here.